# Missing disk space on new installation

Tags: server, partitioning, 22.04, disk-usage

I've installed from scratch Ubuntu 22.04LTS and I found that the available disk space is half of what it should be. This is the second time it happened but in first case I thought it was by my mistake. For some reason `cfdisk` or `fdisk` are reporting that the disk size is 32GB:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 32 GiB, 34359738368 bytes, 67108864 sectors
Disk model: QEMU HARDDISK   
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: DBA31C33-C478-435C-BECA-08D640FCA9DC

Device       Start      End  Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     4095     2048   1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2     4096  4198399  4194304   2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  4198400 67106815 62908416  30G Linux filesystem
```

but unfortunately `df` reports only half of it:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              795M 1016K  794M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   15G  2.7G   12G  20% /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          2.0G  127M  1.7G   7% /boot
tmpfs                              795M  4.0K  795M   1% /run/user/1000
```

and there is no space available to resize the partition so the question is what is going on?

Previously I've seen this on NUC device so I can rule out QEMU issues.

Comment: This seems to have happened on the move from 22.04.1 to 22.04.2. This is really, *really*, dumb. On a 20G *server* install the new installer has seen fit to give me 10G of free space (seriously?! I'm running lots of servers - do you think I need to be given free space 'just in case'?) The answer is simple: trash the install, start again, spend more time on the 'Storage configuration' page.

Answer (score 5):

`lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` and then
`resize2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed Ubuntu with LVM as the disk partitioner. Good man, I salute you. Its a wise choice. But it will act as a more complex environment.

Open up a command prompt and enter the command: **sudo pvs**
This will tell you what physical disks you have installed. We are expecting to see /dev/sda here and for it to say that the PSize is somewhere in the vacinity of 32GB

Next do **sudo vgs**
Now you will see the volume groups. we are expecting to see ubuntu--vg (it may be something slightly different) and for it to report how much is used and how much is free. I would expect to see about 15GB free space here.

If that is roughly what you see, then you are good. What you have is the root partition running in 15GB, which should be OK. And about 15GB of free space. Now you have options. The first is that you mount /home in this free space by creating a new logical volume. That way you can separate your files from the Ubuntu OS files, and if you ever need to rebuild Ubuntu from scratch you don't wipe out all your files in the process.  Or you can extend the root partition in to this free space and get all your data back.

But before you do anything, do the command **sudo lvs**
This will show you what logical volumes you have defined, even if they are not mounted. Just make sure it really is free space, and not a logical volume that is not, for some reason, mounted. This shouldn't be the case, but just be safe before you nuke something important!

If you need further help on this - reach out. LVM is great, its really cool, and at some point it will get you out of a deep hole. But its not trivial!

Comment: While I often suggest /home or separate data partitions, you have only 30GB on  drive. And now with snaps that is not large for / much less /home. I would keep only one volume and plan on regular housecleaning. You may want to consider not using the default snaps, but install the .debs, but in some cases like Firefox they do not make it easy. I uninstall all snaps, use Kubuntu which is a bit smaller and / is using 15GB,, but all data is in other partitions.

Comment: ok, indeed there was additional missing 15GB in vgs. Question is why starting from 22.04 it is not using 100% of space. I am pretty sure it wasn't like this in the past (20.04)

Comment: I will put a test together over the next few days and see if I encounter the same issue.

I remember when I got my first hard drive - 40 MB! ANd it was a dream. Now we look at a 15GB partition and say thats too small. Is this progress?

Comment: Great explanation!  Adding the commands for your resolve would seal the deal on best answer :) (& why LVM is superior to the alternative(s))